# Get char from Unicode value - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm translating a piece of code from VB to Objective C. It contains the function ChrW(), that gives the char from a unicode value passed as integer. How can implement it in Objective C?

Many thanks

Comment: Define `char`. Do you mean the ASCII character code? Do you mean the Unicode character code? Do you mean something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", unicodeValue];
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW2):

> **%C**: 16-bit Unicode character (unichar), printed by NSLog() as an ASCII character, or, if not an ASCII character, in the octal format \ddd or the Unicode hexadecimal format \udddd, where d is a digit

For example, you can get the same results as the example in the documentation of [ChrW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Dim MyChar As Char
MyChar = Chr(65)   ' Returns "A".
MyChar = Chr(97)   ' Returns "a".
MyChar = Chr(62)   ' Returns ">".
MyChar = Chr(37)   ' Returns "%".
```

And in Objective C:

```
NSString *c;
c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 65]; // @"A"
c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 97]; // @"a"
c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 62]; // @">"
c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 37]; // @"%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `NSNumber` class?

```
NSNumber *unicode = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:250];
char myChar = [unicode charValue];
```

Since a unicode character is just an unsigned short, you can get the numeric value like that.